# NativeScript How to hide tab buttons from TabView

Tags: nativescript

I've got a TabView in my NativeScript page. The tabs content is programmatically populated.

How to hide / collapse the tabs buttons (because the tabs are switched programmatically)?

[image]

see Image above of TabView buttons bar - which needs to be collapsed

Comment: You could review the example here - https://github.com/tsonevn/HideTabs_TabView/blob/master/app/main-page.ts#L11-L45, where has been shown how to hide TabView Tabs for both iOS and Android

Answer (score 4):

You can try

For ios:

```
var myTabView = page.getViewById("myTabView")
myTabView.ios.tabBar.hidden = true;
```

For android

```
myTabView.android.removeViewAt(1);
```

Comment: For IOS this hides the tabView but leaves an empty space where it was as if it was just transparent.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution for android (I hope i translated it correctly from my working nativescript angular code)

```
  const tabLayout = myTabView.android.tabLayout;

  // use native android methods to hide the tabLayout containing the tab buttons
  if(isFullscreen) {
    tabLayout.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
  } else {
    tabLayout.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
  }
```